# Connect SBCL on Windows to SQL Server using Integrated Authentication

Tags: sql-server, lisp, odbc, common-lisp, sbcl

What is the path of least resistance in getting an SBCL application running on Windows to connect to a SQL Server instance, using integrated authentication?

I have found posts on connecting from CL-SQL to SQL Server using ODBC connections but as far as I can tell, there is no way to this without first manually setting up a DSN.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [cl-mssql](http://code.google.com/p/cl-mssql/) library that uses FreeTDS to communicate with MSSQL server. According to http://www.freetds.org/userguide/domains.htm, FreeTDS will use Integrated Authentication if you specify the login like 'DOMAIN\Username'. So it might work with cl-mssql (though I haven't used it).

Comment: I ran into some dll issues setting this up on Windows but I'd like to revisit this solution. In the meantime, I've successfully used plain-odbc as detailed separately for comment and future reference.

Answer (score 2):

The path of least resistance for this (SBCL, Windows, no-DSN) seems to be [plain-odbc](http://www.cliki.net/plain-odbc).

```
(asdf:load-system :plain-odbc)
(use-package :plain-odbc)
(setf conn (connect-generic :driver "{SQL Server}"
                            :database "dbname"
                            :server "servername"
                            :trusted_connection "yes"))
(exec-query conn "select * from some_table")
```

Don't use (connect-sql-server ...) as it requires a default DSN, *default-sql-server-dsn*.

There may be a better driver to specify, as well.

Comment: As of April 2015 the project page for plain-odbc is down, and a bit of Googling has thus far yielded me nothing.